# Nimber mnemonic combinatorial puzzle

Tags: mathematics, visual, geometry, combinatorics

Please see my [previous question](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/123357/nimber-mnemonics) for more background.

---

The following represents an unfolded version of [PG(3,2)](https://www.geogebra.org/m/zre6f8zk) with 1 as the center point:

[image]

---

Given that each number must be an end point of a line which passes thru the origin at 1, how can the numbers 2-15 be added such that each line thru the origin has as it's endpoints numbers whose nim product is 1 (eg. the pairs 2/3, 4/15, 5/12, 6/9, 7/11, 8/10 & 13/14)

---

**Hint** The problem reduces to solving the 3 triangles with 1 in the middle (the pieces that fold into the center). It is easy to randomly [fill in the lines](https://q.uiver.app/#q=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), but the goal is to get each of the 3 triangles to satisfy being valid nimonics (eg. straight lines have as their midpoint their product).

---

**See also**  [multiplication chart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nimber#Addition_and_multiplication_tables) + [calculator](https://hypersurreal.github.io/_/*/) (under the graph)

Comment: Can you please label the unknowns in the figure so that it is clear which ones need to take the same value?

Comment: @RobPratt Updated!

Comment: Thanks. For the dotted triangles, which entry is the midpoint?

Comment: @RobPratt Corners are strange. j*h=b (eg. 2 points on the dotted have their shared corner as the sum)

Comment: *product not sum

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 384 solutions.  Here's one:

> a=10, b=4, c=2, d=13, e=7, f=5, g=6, h=9, i=12, j=14, k=11, l=8, m=3, n=15

I used integer linear programming as follows.  Let $$P=\{a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n, o\}$$ be the set of positions, where position $o$ must take value $1$.  Let $V=\{1,\dots,15\}$ be the set of values.  For $i,j\in V$, let $m(i,j)$ be the nim product of $i$ and $j$.
Let $L$ be the set of lines $(p_1,p_2,p_3)$ for which the value assigned to position $p_2$ must be the nim product of the values assigned to positions $p_1$ and $p_3$.  For $p\in P$ and $v\in V$, let binary decision variable $x_{p,v}$ indicate whether position $p$ is assigned value $v$.  The constraints are:
\begin{align}
\sum_{v \in V} x_{p,v} &= 1 && \text{for $p \in P$} \tag1\label1 \\
\sum_{p \in P} x_{p,v} &= 1 && \text{for $v \in V$} \tag2\label2 \\
x_{o,1} &= 1 \tag3\label3 \\
x_{p_1, v_1} + x_{p_3, v_3} - 1 &\le x_{p_2, m(v_1,v_3)} &&\text{for $(p_1,p_2,p_3) \in L$, $v_1 \in V$, and $v_3 \in V$} \tag4\label4
\end{align}
Constraint \eqref{1} assigns one value to each position.
Constraint \eqref{2} assigns each value to one position.
Constraint \eqref{3} assigns position $o$ the value $1$.
Constraint \eqref{4} enforces the logical implication
$$(x_{p_1, v_1} \land x_{p_3, v_3}) \implies x_{p_2, m(v_1,v_3)}$$
that expesses the requirement that the midpoint is the nim product of the two endpoints.

Comment: Brilliant! How many solutions do u think there are? 

Comment: Also, if u don't mind sharing, how exactly did u go about tackling this?